# Audacity Crash at Startup with Ubutnu Studio 22.04 LTS and Terratec Phase88 PCI (Ice1712 Envy24)

Tags: startup, crash, ubuntu-studio, soundcard, audacity

First of all I'm sorry for my bad English.

My Setup

- Asus P6X58D-E
  -Xeon 5670
- 6x4GB of DDR3 1600Mhz Ram
- R9 370 GPU
- Terratec Phase 88 PCI with RCA Ice/VT1712 Envy24 (And this is probably the key to the problem)
- A BX500 SSD plugged into Sata 6 Gb/s on the Marvell 88SE9128
- A PS/2 keyboard and a USB mouse.
- Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS

Audacity crashes on startup and does not launch, I tried with another u-Phoria UMC204HD sound card on the same setup without the Terratec and Audacity works:

Do you have an idea, thank you